# Could anyone Identify the error for me in this YAML file?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I can't find the error from what it's telling me:

```
243
should match exactly one schema in oneOf
244
should be equal to one of the allowed values allowedValues: query, header,     cookie
```

The 244 error is kinda really strange since he's saying if I'm replacing path with query I should use one of the valid statements where then instead of query path is written in the error code.

This errors just appear if i have the `IstGeloescht` param in it. When I remove the whole block, it's fine, but as far as i know it should be correct. Since I've seen some errors are hidden and only appear when we fix something else, I decided to show you all of the code.

```
openapi: 3.0.0
servers: []
info:
  description:  REST API
  version: "1.0.0"
  title:  REST API
  contact:
    email: info@lala.net
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html'
tags:
  - name: Adresse
    description: Adressendpunkt der REST API
```

paths:

/v2/ADR/Adresse:

```
get:
  tags:
    - Adresse
  summary: Gibt alle Adressen zurück.
  operationId: V2ADRAdresseGet
  description: |
    Gibt alle Adressen der zurück.
  parameters:
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/Sort'
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/Limit'
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/Offset'
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/Filter'
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/Depth'
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/Fields'
    - $ref: '#/components/parameters/IstGeloescht'

  responses:
    '200':
      description: search results matching criteria
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/adresseModell'
    '400':
      description: bad input parameter
```

components:

schemas:

```
adresseModell: 
  required: 
    - Name
    - PLZ
    - Ort
  type: object
  properties: 
    AdressNr: 
      format: int32
      type: integer
    Name: 
      description: "Beinhaltet Firmenname bei Firmenadressen"
      maxLength: 40
      type: string
    Vorname: 
      description: Optional
      maxLength: 40
      type: string
    Strasse: 
      description: Optional
      maxLength: 40
      type: string
    PLZ: 
      maxLength: 10
      type: string
    Ort: 
      maxLength: 40
      type: string
    Geloescht: 
      description: "Kann nicht gefiltert werden, URL-Parameter verwenden"
      type: boolean
    Adressgruppen: 
      description: "dieses Feld kann nicht gefiltert oder sortiert werden"
      uniqueItems: false
      type: string
    Anrede: 
      description: Optional
      maxLength: 40
      type: string
    Bemerkungen: 
      description: Optional
      maxLength: 100000
      type: string
    EMail: 
      description: Optional
      maxLength: 100
      type: string
    TelDirekt: 
      description: Optional
      maxLength: 40
      type: string
    TelZentrale: 
      description: Optional
      maxLength: 40
      type: string
    TelPrivat: 
      description: Optional
      maxLength: 40
      type: string
    Fax: 
      description: Optional
      maxLength: 40
      type: string
    Mobiltelefon: 
      description: Optional
      maxLength: 40
      type: string
    Homepage: 
      description: Optional
      maxLength: 100
      type: string
    PLZPostfach: 
      description: Optional
      maxLength: 50
      type: string
    Postfach: 
      description: Optional
      maxLength: 50
      type: string
    Region: 
      description: Optional
      type: string
    Land: 
      type: string
      description: Optional
    Longitude: 
      format: double
      description: Optional
      type: number
    Latitude: 
      format: double
      description: Optional
      type: number
    DebitorenSteuercode: 
      type: string
      description: Optional
    DebitorenSteuercodeVerwenden: 
      description: "Bei True wird der Steuercode der Adresse verwendet und übersteuert andere Steuercodes, optional"
      type: boolean
    DebitorenErtragskonto: 
      type: string
      description: Optional
    DebitorenErtragskontoVerwenden: 
      description: "Bei True wird der Steuercode der Adresse verwendet und übersteuert andere Steuercodes, optional"
      type: boolean
    DebitorenWaehrung: 
      type: string
      description: Optional
    DebitorenKostenstelle: 
      type: string
      description: Optional
    DebitorenKostenstelleVerwenden: 
      description: "Bei True wird der Steuercode der Adresse verwendet und übersteuert andere Steuercodes, optional"
      type: boolean
    DebitorenKostenart: 
      type: string
      description: Optional
    DebitorenKostenartVerwenden: 
      description: "Bei True wird der Steuercode der Adresse verwendet und übersteuert andere Steuercodes, optional"
      type: boolean
    DebitorenRabatt: 
      format: double
      description: Optional
      type: number
    Vertreter: 
      type: string
      description: Optional
    Lagerpreis: 
      format: int32
      description: Optional
      type: integer
    Geburtsdatum: 
      description: Optional
      type: string
    ErstelltAm: 
      type: string
    ErstelltVon: 
      type: string
    GeaendertAm: 
      type: string
    GeaendertVon: 
      type: string
    Zusatzfelder: 
      type: object
    additionalProperties: 
      type: object
```

parameters:

```
Sort:
  in: query
  name: sort
  schema:
    type: integer
  description: Kommagetrennte Liste der Felder die aufsteigend sortiert werden sollen (ein Minus vor der Feldbezeichnung sortiert absteigend), eingebette Objekte können nur nach dem Primärschlüssel sortiert werden

Limit:
  in: query
  name: limit
  schema:
    type: integer
  description: Limitiert die Anzahl Datensätze die zurückgegeben wird

Offset:
  in: query
  name: offset
  schema:
    type: integer
  description: Legt fest bei welchem Datensatz gestartet werden soll

Filter:
  in: query
  name: filter
  schema:
    type: integer
  description: Ermöglicht innerhalb eines Felds nach Werten zu filtern (Details im Kapitel Filter Syntax)

Depth:
  in: query
  name: depth
  schema:
    type: integer
  description: Gibt an, wie viele Hierarchie-Stufen an Unterobjekten komplett eingebettet werden sollen (Details im Kapitel Einbettungstiefe)

Fields:
  in: query
  name: fields
  schema: 
    type: integer
  description: Kommagetrennte Liste der Felder welche zurückgegeben werden sollen (der Primärschlüssel wird in jedemfall zurückgegeben)

IstGeloescht:
  in: path
  name: istgeloescht
  schema:
    type: string
    enum:
      - yes
      - no
      - any
  description: Kommagetrennte Liste der Felder welche zurückgegeben werden sollen (der Primärschlüssel wird in jedemfall zurückgegeben)
```

Comment: To recap the linked Q&A - your path parameter `IstGeloescht` is missing `required: true`.

Comment: it's not required but now i changed path to query and the error disaperas (after my lunch) may a editor error from swagger hub? Ah it's Written here i have overreaded it. 

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/  on Required and Optional parameters

Answer (score 0):

Is `IstGeloescht` supposed to be a **path parameter** (`/v2/ADR/Adresse/{IstGeloescht}`) or a **query parameter** (`/v2/ADR/Adresse?IstGeloescht=...`)? It's currently defined as a path parameter - if so, you need to update the path and add `required: true` to the path parameter. If it's a query parameter, change `in: path` to `in: query` instead.

Also, some YAML parsers handle `yes` and `no` as the boolean values `true` and `false`. I'd suggest enclosing these values in quotes to make sure they are parsed as strings.

```yaml
        enum:
          - 'yes'   # <------
          - 'no'    # <------
          - any
```

Comment: Thank you for this i was already wondering. :)